# Sencha Touch not launching in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, mobile-safari, android-browser

I've been working on a Sencha Touch 2.1-based mobile app for a while, mostly testing with desktop Chrome and a PhoneGap / Cordova package on iOS. Recently I decided I want to launch it as a "native" app and also a web app with reduced functionality.

In my tests, the web app will load on desktop browsers (Safari and Chrome for Mac), but not mobile browsers (I've tested Safari and Chrome on iOS, and the Android 2.3 browser).

I'm testing with the package build, but the testing build doesn't fair any better. Using Safari developer console, I can see the Ext object seems to be fully loaded, and all my views, controllers, models, and stores are loaded into my app's namespace -- however, the `app` and `config` properties are *not* present, and the `launch()` function is never run. There are no errors in the console.

Anyone run across this problem & know a solution (or some troubleshooting hints)?

Comment: What are you using on the server side? .NET by chance?

Comment: I've built a simple REST API in Flask, but the app never gets to the point of sending a request. The host is serving the static resources with nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inclusion of `cordova.js` in app.json caused the immediate problem. But the larger problem appears to be the fact that production builds of Sencha Touch don't include external libraries in a way that makes them accessible to the app. Although I thought I was having problems with package and testing builds earlier, at this point I am finding that only production builds break, and only when including external libraries (in my case, `cordova.js`).

Answer (score 1):

Could you confirm your app.json? If you added the path for cordova.js with "x-bootstrap": true , the file is never copied into destination of your build.

```
"js": [
    {
        "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js",
        "x-bootstrap": true
    },
    {
        "path": "lib/cordova.js",
        /*"x-bootstrap": true*/
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true,
        "update": "delta"
    }
],
```